# How to select sum but includes other column?

Tags: sql, select

I want to select sum group by an identifier column and it can include other column if the data to be summed is only one row in that column (no sum is happening). However, if there are many rows and they are summed, let the data from the other column empty or null.

For example, I have this table

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| Amount | Identifier |  Expired   |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      8 | a          | 2020-01-01 |
|      6 | b          | 2020-01-02 |
|     -2 | c          | 2020-01-01 |
|     -3 | c          | 2020-01-01 |
|      2 | d          | 2020-01-03 |
|     -3 | e          | 2020-01-01 |
|     -5 | e          | 2020-01-02 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

After select, I want this result

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| Amount | Identifier |  Expired   |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      8 | a          | 2020-01-01 |
|      6 | b          | 2020-01-02 |
|     -5 | c          |            |
|      2 | d          | 2020-01-03 |
|     -8 | e          |            |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

How can I achieve this with sql query?

Notes: I use postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group` by `Identifier` and add `aggregate` function on other columns too.

```
select
    sum(Amount) as Amount,
    Identifier,
    max(Expired) as Expired
from TableNameXYZ
group by Identifier;
```

Or to achieve result as per your output -

```
select
    sum(Amount) as Amount,
    Identifier,
    (case when count(1) > 1 then null else max(Expired) end) as Expired
from TableNameXYZ
group by Identifier;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can do like below

```
select sum(Amount),Identifier,(case when count(*) > 1 then null else min(Expired) END) 'Expired' from [dbo].[Test] 
group by Identifier
```